# MySQL sql query LIKE to get current opening hours

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

So, in my mysql database I am storing days and hours open in one field, called `days`, the data is stored in the following format:

`[Monday:9:17[Tuesday:9:17[Wednesday:10:18[`

As you may've guessed, it goes: `[Day:From:Till`   and brackets are just seperatars for PHP to distinguish how many days are there.

I've been thinking all day what query would be but I could not figure out, so basically I need to get current date and time using PHP:

```
date(l); // Day in full text representation.
date(G); // current hour in 24 hour format.
```

So basically I need a query which in simple english would sound like:

> SELECT all FROM businessdetails WHERE column date CONTAINS [current date] and :#:# numbers to be less than current hour and greater than current hour.

Help? My brain is melting by now.

Comment: Serialized data of this sort is *extremely* annoying to query. Are you sure you can't create a properly [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) data structure to avoid all of this?

Comment: can't really, I am working in a company and my boss just gave this to me, so I need to come up with any possible way

Comment: like tadman said, if you could have a second table with a single column for From and a single column for Till then you could query where From < G and Till > G

Comment: That is a horrific data structure. You should use MySQL for what it was intended for: storing relational data in separate tables and linking them with a foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So honestly the best thing to do is to normalize your database so you can do better queries. BUT I love to see if I can solve impossible situations so here is what you can do!

**This will check all the business that are open on Tuesday at 11am**

```
SELECT * FROM `businessdetails` WHERE `date` REGEXP 'Tuesday:(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11):(11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23)[^0-9]'
```

(Funny thing I've found I can't seem to escape the `[` in the column so I had to make sure the Regex doesn't have any extra digits at the end or it may erroneously match 2 and 20 or something.)

Here's how you can generate that REGEXP string via PHP:

```
<?php

$regexp = date('l') . ':(' . join('|', range(0, date('G'))) . '):(' . join('|', range(date('G'), 23)) . ')[^0-9]';
```

**DISCLAIMER** I don't actually recommend doing this but I thought it was clever and wanted to share since it directly answers your question.

Comment: I have to +1 this due to how ballsy it is. Hah!

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT

Just noticed you changed your answer. below may not apply anymore, but I'll leave it for future reference...

---

I would suggest having a separate child table for this.

### STORES

```
auto increment ID
   |  
   |  the store name     the store description   etc..
   |    /                     /                  /
.--------------------------------------------------.
| id | name             | description        | etc |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | mary's kitchen   | a fancy restaurant | etc |
| 2  | willow creek inn | we serve breakfast | etc |
'--------------------------------------------------'
```

### STORE_HOURS

```
auto increment ID
   |          The STORES.id
   |                /         the day (0-SUN, 6-SAT)
   |      _________/          /     the 24h time OPEN (HH:MM:SS *TIME*)
   |     /          _________/ ____/      the 24h time CLOSE (HH:MM:SS *TIME*)
   |    /          /          /          /
.----------------------------------------------.
| id | store_id | day | time_open | time_close |
| 1  | 1        | 1   | 08:30:00  | 20:00:00   |
| 2  | 1        | 2   | 08:30:00  | 20:00:00   |
| 3  | 1        | 3   | 10:30:00  | 20:00:00   |
| 4  | 1        | 4   | 11:00:00  | 20:00:00   |
| 5  | 1        | 5   | 08:30:00  | 22:30:00   |
'----------------------------------------------'
```

Now, depending on what you want to display, you could query the table:

```
SELECT
  stores.name AS store_name,
  stores.description AS store_description,
  store_hours.day AS store_hours_day,
  TIME(store_hours.time_open) AS store_open,
  TIME(store_hours.time_close) AS store_close
FROM
  stores
JOIN
  store_hours
ON
  store_hours.store_id = stores.id
```

Result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6872/8/0

With this table structure and relationship, you can then create granular queries without too much effort.

Comment: A great structure and some amazing ASCII art.

Answer (score 1):

So this might be a hell of a response, but here is one way to do it... (Although I'm sure there must be more significantly better ways:

```
$day = date(l); // Day in full text representation.
$time = date(G);  // current hour in 24 hour format. 

$sql = "SELECT businessID FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(t_time,':',1) as start, SUBSTRING_INDEX(LEFT(t_time,POSITION('[' IN t_time) - 1), ':',-1) as end,businessID  from (SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(`column_date`,POSITION('$day' IN `column_date`) + LENGTH('" . $day . "') + 1),':',2) as t_time, businessID  from `businessdetails ` where `column_date` like '%$day%') as t_table_1) as t_table_2 where start >= $time && end <= $time";
```

Hopefully that works =)

PS If you need help there are all these string functions you could use:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: +1 haha nice! I don't know if you saw my regex solution or not but I like yours too. Not that anyone should do either of our solutions ;)

Comment: Agreed =P I really like your regex solution though lol A little... cleaner.. than mine lol

Comment: You shouldn't be putting things like `$time` directly in your query. That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @tadman a) I'd love to know how it's a recipe for disaster considering no one has access to change it.... and b) It was just an example of how to get it done. It was mainly to create the SQL that would get the job done. I left it up to the user to figure out the PHP that would be needed to be 100% perfect considering his code was probably an example and not the real thing....

Comment: I ended up doing bit different way, I ended up calling all businesses that day LIKE '%Today%' then comparing current time bigger or equal to opening hours and smaller to closing time and showing only those results. This way there isn't 500 queries called, I know it's dumb way, but I have no other choice but to work with this type formatted db

Comment: @AramPapazian String interpolation in general produces very hard to audit queries. You must be absolutely certain that no user data is being substituted there which is why using placeholders like `?` and  `bind_param` is the most reliable method for ensuring a safe, bug-free query. You get in the habit of doing this way, then you make one mistake, then your site is completely destroyed by a [SQL hacking tool](http://sqlmap.org/). Unless the question is *specifically* asking for legacy `mysql_query` code, **always** use placeholders.

Comment: @tadman true, but then if you use bind_param there would be no way for you to easily be able to see what the query was that was making a call (You can't just simply var_dump it) Although bind_param may be the safest way, it's not the best for debugging when issues arise in the code. I guess for me it's easier to audit interpolated code than to debug binded queries =/ Although I'll check out the details more and update my antics based on necessities =)

Comment: This is not even an issue. You can dump the query and the values you're binding together, and if they're named like `:id` instead of `?` it's not even hard to see what's going on. Interpolated code is **extremely** risky as a single mistake can compromise your entire application and possibly your business and career. If you need to know exactly what SQL is being executed, turn on [MySQL general query logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html).